Dolbeault cohomology of compact support
Hartogs' extension theorem holds for dimensions $n>1$. The proof relies on the fact that if $n>1$, the equation $\bar{\partial}u = f$, where $f$ is a smooth $(0,1)$-form with compact support, is solved by the unique compactly supported smooth function $u$. Does this mean that $H_c^{(0,1)}(\mathbb{C}^n) = 0$ only for $n>1$? Can I regard this as a complex analog of the fact that $H_c^n(\mathbb{R}^m) = 0$ for $m\ne n$? I am asking this because I cannot find any calculations or materials about Dolbeault cohomology with compact support.

I am not familiar with an "elementary" calculation of Dolbeault cohomology with compact support, but there is a general approach: Serre duality. We need only the following special case.

Theorem. (e.g., Banica, Stanasila - "Algebraic methods in the global theory of complex spaces", Theorem I.2.1)
If $M$ is a Stein manifold of dimension $n$, $E$ is a holomorphic vector bundle on $M$, then $H_c^q(M, E)$ is a dual space of $H^{n-q}(M, E^* \otimes \Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is the line bundle of holomorphic differential forms of degree $n$.

Applying this to trivial bundle we obtain that $H^{0,q}_c(M)$ is isomorphic to the dual space of $H^{n, n-q}(M)$. Since the latter cohomology space is nontrivial on Stein manifolds (in patricular, when $M = \mathbb C^n$) only if $n-q = 0$, whe obtain that $H^{0,q}_c(M)$ is nontrivial only if $q = n$.

Thank you, are Stein manifolds the (only) usual setting for Serre duality to hold on a noncompact space?

No, there are a lot more situations that lead to some version of Serre duality. For the reference you can check the same book of Banica and Stanasila, Chapter VII. @okaberintarou

I'll check it, thanks!
